# Google App Engine - Design for a efficient datastore model for grouped organisations and members

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I've read the Google documentation over and over and googled a fair bit but I'm struggling to design the most efficient datastore “model” for my application. I want to keep latency and datastore operations at a minimum. I have a background in relational databases and this is polluting my thoughts when working with datastore.

My application context:

A national organisation is broken down into a hierarchy of regional organisations and each regional organisation into a hierarchy of local organisations. Overall three levels of hierarchy: National-Regional-Local.

Each organisation has members; the national organisation has direct members, who are also direct members of one or more regional and one or more local organisations. Similarly direct members of a regional organisation are direct members of one or more local organisations possibly in one or more region.

Any member of any local organisation may be a member of any other local, regional, local in another region or national organisation.

A member of a local organisation is under the jurisdiction of the local organisation’s regional organisation and the national organisation but not necessarily a direct member of the regional or national organisation.

Any direct member/organisation pair (a subscription) has its own properties e.g. start date, status etc.

My initial reaction would be to define 3 kinds: Member, Organisation and Subscription.

Organisation entities would have a property for a relation to its parent regional (or national if it’s a region) organisation. Thus forming a hierarchy.

A Subscription entity would have a property for a relation to a member and a property for a relation to an organisation. This representing direct membership.

A member entity has contact details e.g. email address.

I want to perform operations (e.g. send an email or message) based on the hierarchy of organisations and members. For example:

1. Send a message to a local organisation’s direct members.
2. Send a message to a regional organisation’s direct members but not
   the members of the regions local organisations who aren’t direct
   members of the regional organisation.
3. Send a message to a regional organisation’s direct members and the
   direct members of all local organisations under that region. (The
   message would go to a member who is a direct member of the region
   and a direct member of one or more sub local organisations just
   once.)

Does anyone have any suggestions on the design of the model i.e. Kinds, Relations especially with regards to the necessary queries required to get a distinct list of members email addresses for each of the messaging scenarios above?